# Jquery append method returning html tags instead of the proper formats

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

The feature is for a quiz and im retrieving the data for the quiz that is the questions and answers and appending it to my div having id test_box. The data has been successfully retrieved but instead of proper formatting the data, it is returning me in form of html tags.

Here is my code snippet:

```
 const url = window.location.href

 const testBox = document.getElementById('test_box')


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `${url}/data`,
    success: function(response){
        const data = response.data
        data.forEach(element => {
            for (const [question, answers] of Object.entries(element)){
                 testBox.append(`
                 <div class="question_box">
                     <div>
                        <b>${question}</b>
                     </div>
                     `);
                 answers.forEach(answer => {
                    testBox.append(`
                     <div>
                         <input type="radio" class="ans" id=${question}-${answer}" name="${question}" 
                         value="${answer}">
                         <label for="${question}">${answer}</label>
                    </div>
                     `)
                 })
                 testBox.append(`</div>`);
            }
        
        });
    },
     error: function(error){
         console.log(error)
     }
});
```

output of response.data

```
 Array(2)0: {1000-100 = ?: Array(4)}1: {1 + 1 = ?: Array(4)}length: 
 2__proto__: 
 Array(0)
```

Comment: Please elaborate more and show output of `data` as well.

Comment: @Swati, the ouput becomes like this: <div class="question_box"> <div> <b>1 + 1 = ?</b> </div> <div> <input type="radio" class="ans"......

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById('test_box')` use `$("#test_box").append..` don't mix jquery and js .

Comment: @Swati, it becomes ok. But the divs are not rendering right. I'll post a  picture

Comment: and show output of `response.data`  as well :)

Comment: so you need to keep that border should cover whole radio option as well am i right i.e :  all option should also be inside question_box div ?

Comment: @Swati, riiiight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first append your outer div i.e : `question_box`  inside your dom and then to append option inside your `question_box` you can use `$("#test_box .question_box:last")` this will target last question_box added and will append options there .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo..
var data = [{
  "1000 - 100 = ?": ["a", "v", "c", "d"]
}, {
  " 1 + 1 = ?": ["a", "v", "c", "d"]
}]

data.forEach(element => {
  for (const [question, answers] of Object.entries(element)) {
  //use it like this..
    $("#test_box").append(`
                 <div class="question_box">
                     <div>
                        <b>${question}</b>
                     </div>
                     </div>`);

    answers.forEach(answer => {
    //now to append inside question_box use :last
      $("#test_box .question_box:last").append(`
                     <div>
                         <input type="radio" class="ans" id=${question}-${answer}" name="${question}" 
                         value="${answer}">
                         <label for="${question}">${answer}</label>
                    </div>
                     `)
    })

  }

});
```

```css
.question_box {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test_box"></div>
```